# select control data loop is returning error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

I am loading an HTML select item in Razor for a Webpage using VB.NET.

```
<select name="dropdownEmployees" id="dropdownEmployee" > 
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Employee --</option>

    @For Each row In db.Query(strEmployeeList)
        @<option value="@row.EmployeeID">"@row.Employee"</option>
    Next row

</select>
```

And then I get this error when I try to run the page in a browser:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web  request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Format of the
>   initialization string does not conform to specification starting at
>   index 0.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 63:                         -- Select Employee -- Line 64:
>   Line 65:                         @For Each row In
>   db.Query(strEmployeeList) Line 66:
>   @"@row.Employee" Line 67:
>   Next row

I am not sure what to look at since the syntax looks correct. I am using VB.NET on this project per a client requirement but having done this in C# seems to be similar in comparison.

Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NomexCS" connectionString="Data Source=WEBSQL1\PLCSQL;Initial Catalog=Nomex;User ID=********;Password=*******;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Try removing @ symbol from <option>

Comment: I get a Compilation error with a blue line under the <option> when I remove the @

Comment: @Ryan What is the contents of `strEmployeeList`?

Comment: @Polynomial strEmployeeList is "SELECT ID, Employee FROM dbo.SheeterEmployees" I still cannot seem to get this to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be my connection string. It was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
@For Each row In db.Query(strEmployeeList)
    @<option value=@row.EmployeeID>@row.Employee</option>
Next row
```

Comment: I am using VB.NET. Isn't that C#?